# Spring configuration to call different database environments like dev,int,uat,prod

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I am having a Java standalone application, which is using the Spring core container and spring jdbc. I have different database environments like dev,int,uat,prod. These database configuration details and datasources for each environments are configured in spring configuration file spring-beans.xml along with the DAO beans.
Now i have to update the application, like if i passed a particular the database environment(like dev,int,uat,prod) as arguments at the time of running the application, the application will invoke the database as mentioned in the arguments. is there any way out?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should used spring with hibernate it much easier or you can use JDNI for that

```
db1Jndi=
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root

db2Jndi=
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root
```